# Insert a new line in a specific spot bash

Tags: linux, bash, txt

So basically, I want to get a list of all users in a text file. First, I tried to `ls` the `/home` directory and output it to a file. But when I did this, It just put the users in a list like `user1 user2 user3 user4` but I need the list like this:

```
user1
user2
user3
user4
```

So any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: Try `man ls` - you'll find the `ls -1` command.

Comment: `ls` will normally output one entry per line when its output is going someplace other than a terminal (e.g. to a file), so I suspect the problem has to do with how you're sending the output to a file. How are you doing that? A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help a lot.

Comment: What does this have to do with inserting a new line in a specific spot? Did you mean "newline"? You wouldn't be so much "inserting" as replacing the spaces.

Comment: Are you aware that user home directories aren't necessarily in `/home`? There are more thorough ways to do what you want, for example, `getent passwd | cut -f1 -d:`.

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a list of users directly from `/etc/passwd` by simply excluding the system accounts. You need to know what the `UID_MIN` and `UID_MAX` for your distribution. You can get that simply with, e.g.

```bash
$ grep '^UID_' /etc/login.defs
UID_MIN                  1000
UID_MAX                 60000
```

Now simply output the users from `/etc/passwd` (and optionally sort) excluding UIDs outside that range, e.g.

```bash
$ awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 && $3 <= 60000 { print $1 }' /etc/passwd | sort
alan
anna
darrell
david
deborah
dell
dmimms
drr
...
```

To save to a file, simply redirect the result to a filename of your choosing, e.g.

```bash
$ awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 && $3 <= 60000 { print $1 }' /etc/passwd | sort > filename
```

Comment: `getent passwd {1000..60000}|awk -F: '{print $1 |"sort"}'`

Comment: @ufopilot - that's too good. Thank you.

Comment: After thinking about the brace expansion `{1000..60000}` a bit more, there is one potential issue to be aware of. That will produce a command line containing `59001` words and a total of `345006` characters. On some systems this may exceed `ARG_MAX` (old limit was 128KiB). But on most recent 64-bit Linux implementations, `ARG_MAX` is roughly 2M, making the expansion safe. (but check before using) See [Linux command line character limit](https://serverfault.com/q/163371/332034)

Answer (score 1):

you can try `ls > filename.txt`

Comment: OP said they already tried that, so how would this help? (I know it'll work, but you really need to make it explicit in your answer, for OP's sake.)

Answer (score 1):

With bash's globbing (`*`):

```
cd /home/
printf "%s\n" * >file
```

Output to file:

```
user1
user2
user3
user4
```

See: `help printf`

Answer (score 0):

suggesting to use `find` command.

```
find /home -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf "%f\n"
```

Or better inspect those users who have a valid shell.

Not all users that have a shell have a home directory.

```
awk  -F: '/nologin$/{next}{print $1}' /etc/passwd
```